# Объединение asm и С в один проект для AVR микроконтроллера

Tags: c, ассемблер, gcc, микроконтроллеры

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется программа, написанная на asm для МК atmega328p. В ней реализована передача данных по USART и обработка данных с внешнего АЦП.

Однако появилась необходимость внедрить "С-шные вставки" в ассемблерный код.

Почитав форумы, принялся писать через Atmel Studio Gcc проект, и столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

Пытаюсь инициализировать USART, выставлением битов по необходимым регистрам ( в чистом asm данная часть работает прекрасно), однако в С выдает следующую ошибку:

```
`Error      invalid operands (*ABS* and *UND* sections) for `<<'    GccApplication2 \asmroutine.S`
```

Далее привожу листинги трех файлов:

main.c

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "asmroutine.h"


int main(void)
{
    USART_INIT
        /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) 
    }
}
```

asmroutine.h:

```
#ifndef _ASMROUTINE_
#define _ASMROUTINE_

//Общие определения

#ifdef __ASSEMBLER__

//Определения только для ассемблера

#endif

#ifndef __ASSEMBLER__

//Определения только для С

    USART_INIT;

#endif

#endif
```

asmroutine.S:

```
#include "asmroutine.h"


.global USART_INIT


USART_INIT: 

            LDI     R30, hi8(7)             //Инициализация UART
            STS     UBRR0H,R30                          //Загружаем число 7
            LDI     R30, lo8(7)             //Котрое соответствует скорости 250k бод
            STS     UBRR0L,R30                          

            ldi R30, (1<<UDRE0) | (1<<U2X0)                     //Бит UDRE0 свободен,двойная скорость(см. даташит)
            sts UCSR0A,R30
    

            ldi R30, (1<<TXEN0)|(1<<RXEN0)|(0<<UDRIE0)|(0<<RXCIE0)          //Передача разрешена, разрешены прерывания по опустошению UDRE
            sts UCSR0B,R30                                      

            ldi R30, (0<<USBS0)|(1<<UCSZ01)|(1<<UCSZ00)     //Задаем рамку: 8 бит данных, 1 стоп бит
            sts UCSR0C,R30      
            
ret
```

Если же имена битов регистров заменить на числа: например, вместо `0<<USBS0` написать `0<<1`, то компилятор не ругается.

Соответственно можно сделать вывод, что ошибка кроется где то в названии битов регистра. Однако все названия взяты из даташита и библиотек зависимостей в atmel studio.

Не могли бы вы подсказать, в чем косяк?

Comment: Помогло добавление в файл asmroutine.S следующей строчки:

 `#include <avr/interrupt.h>`

Однако, не ясно для чего ее следует добавлять в ассемблерный код

Comment: У вас не хватает какого-то заголовочного файла. Ищите, что включает в себя _interrupt.h_, ответ где-то там. Не очень понятно, что вы имели в виду под `USART_INIT;` в заголовочном файле. Для Си надо правильно прописывать прототипы функций. Помимо этого, вам надо скачать документ ABI на ваш процессор (архитектуру) и использовать соглашения по использованию регистров, выравниванию и т.п.